# get max(DateTime) from two concatenated colums ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I'm struggling with something and don't have a lot of time to figure it out by myself.

My Query:

```
   Select distinct d.delivery_bay_code,dt.diary_type_desc, d.delivery_datetime, ddo.order_no , ddo.company_id_no,  ddo.no_of_cartons, s.supplier_name, c.company_name, sk.sku_desc, (pod.deliver_not_after_date)||' '||(pod.deliver_not_before_date)as delivery_window
     from diary d , dc_diary_order ddo , purch_order po ,purch_order_carton_sku pocs ,sku sk, purch_order_date pod,supplier s , diary_type dt , company c
    where ddo.diary_entry_id_no = d.diary_entry_id_no
      and po.order_no = ddo.order_no
      and po.company_id_no = ddo.company_id_no
      and s.supplier_id_no = po.supplier_id_no
      and s.company_id_no = po.company_id_no
      and dt.diary_type_code = d.diary_type_code
      and c.company_id_no = po.company_id_no
      and po.order_no = pocs.order_no
      and pocs.sku_id_no = sk.sku_id_no
      and po.company_id_no = 2
      and ddo.order_no = 1999
      order by delivery_datetime;
```

This query brings back 2 records where only the `delivery_window` differs. For example `13/APR/11 13/APR/11 and 12/APR/11 12/APR/11` I want it to only bring back the max datetime(latest date).

For example: `select max(delivery_datetime) from diary;`

Now i have tried my above query like this:

```
select... max(pod.deliver_not_after_date)||' '||(pod.deliver_not_before_date)as delivery_window ... from
```

but i get error `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

Comment: :Thats the basic of sql ,if you want the max record ,the you need to put the non aggregate column in group by clause ,In your query ,you are using distinct clause ,which can gave you multiple records ,so what is the criteria to get max delivery date ,if you want you can use analytical function

Comment: FYI: the max will apply to max(date1) only. You will not get max from range of dates as max(date1)||' '||date2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `GROUP BY` on `pod.deliver_not_before_date`, that is causing the error message.

```
select... max(pod.deliver_not_after_date)||' '||(pod.deliver_not_before_date)as delivery_window ... from ..... GROUP BY pod.deliver_not_before_date
```

When using a `MAX()` or any other grouping function, all other columns that don't have a grouping function must be put into the `GROUP BY` part of your SQL statement.

To get only the row with the latest date for each order, you can use something like:

```
   select *
       from (
             Select distinct d.delivery_bay_code,dt.diary_type_desc, d.delivery_datetime, ddo.order_no , ddo.company_id_no,  ddo.no_of_cartons, s.supplier_name, c.company_name, sk.sku_desc, (pod.deliver_not_after_date)||' '||(pod.deliver_not_before_date)as delivery_window
             , max(pod.deliver_not_after_date) over (partition by ddo.order_no order by ddo.order_no) max_deliver_not_after_date
          from diary d , dc_diary_order ddo , purch_order po ,purch_order_carton_sku pocs ,sku sk, purch_order_date pod,supplier s , diary_type dt , company c
            where ddo.diary_entry_id_no = d.diary_entry_id_no
          and po.order_no = ddo.order_no
          and po.company_id_no = ddo.company_id_no
          and s.supplier_id_no = po.supplier_id_no
          and s.company_id_no = po.company_id_no
          and dt.diary_type_code = d.diary_type_code
          and c.company_id_no = po.company_id_no
          and po.order_no = pocs.order_no
          and pocs.sku_id_no = sk.sku_id_no
          and po.company_id_no = 2
          and ddo.order_no = 1999
          order by delivery_datetime)
      where deliver_not_after_date = max_deliver_not_after_date;
```